# Pattern to avoid long dot-notation chains

Tags: javascript

When accessing nested objects using dot notation, I always have to make sure that the previous object exists, which gets pretty exhausting.

I basically want to avoid long if chains like

```
if (a && a.b && a.b.c && a.b.c[0] ... ) { v = a.b.c[0]; }
```

The only other thing I can think of is via the use of a try catch.

```
var v; try { v = a.b.c[0].d.e; } catch (e) {}
```

Is there a better pattern for this?

Comment: I see a recursive function coming to mind... **thinking**

Comment: @tymeJV I do not see any recursion here :)

Comment: I was thinking something like a function to check the first field, if it exists, check the second..so on so forth till the nth field.

Comment: I think the same, but iterative solution seems to be as easy as a recursional one

Comment: It is not possible without causing an exception to ask *up front* past a.b (for example a.b.c throws an exception).

Comment: You should generally avoid stringing so many calls. Create a method to do what you want instead of train wrecking http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?TrainWreck

Comment: The only way to find out if you can dereference is to look.  There is no way in the native language to do look-ahead beyond one or two steps.  @elimirks has a point, this is a bit of an anti-pattern to begin with from an OOP standpoint, but still something we run into from time to time.

Comment: @elimirks The problem is I you have no choice when accessing e.g. decoded JSON objects. That's not a design decision.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you've got the two prettiest solutions already.

But note that for something like, say, `obj.obj.string.length` your first solution will fail if `string === ""`. Since an empty string is falsey, it'll trip the `&&` guard.

But speaking of strings, you *could* do something like:

```
function getNestedProperty(obj, propChain) {
    var props = propChain.slice(0), prop = props.shift();
    if(typeof obj[prop] !== "undefined") {
        if(props.length) {
            return getNestedProperty(obj[prop], props);
        } else {
            return obj[prop];
        }
    }
}

var v = getNestedProperty(a, ["b", "c", 0, "d", "e"]);
```

Yeah... not too pretty :P

I'd say that, of the solutions proposed, `try...catch` is probably the simplest way to go

Answer (score 0):

How about this one:

```
var hasProperty = function (object, property) {

    var properties = property.split('.'),
        temp = object;

    while (temp && properties.length) {
        temp = temp[properties.shift()];
    }

    return !!temp;
};
```

and then use it like:

```
if (a && hasProperty(a, 'b.c.0' ) { v = a.b.c[0]; }
```

Answer (score 0):

The scenario you are referring to in your question is also called "optional chaining". Some languages already support it by now – for example C# has so called [null-conditional operators](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/null-conditional-operators) which allow you to short-circuit your expressions:

```
var count = customers?[0]?.Orders?.Count();
```

Unfortunately, this feature has not yet made it into the current JS specifications.

There is an open [Stage 1](https://tc39.github.io/process-document/) proposol for "optional chaining" that can be tracked [here](https://github.com/tc39/proposal-optional-chaining).

This would allow you to write...

```
a?.b[3].c?.(x).d
```

...instead of:

```
a == null ? undefined : a.b[3].c == null ? undefined : a.b[3].c(x).d
```

If you want to take the risk and use it already at this early stage, you can [target it via babel](https://babeljs.io/docs/en/babel-plugin-proposal-optional-chaining) to include it in your project.

Answer (score -1):

It's rather evil, but this should work and doesn't look too horrible:

```
var i = !a ? null : !a.b ? null : !a.b.c ? null : !a.b.c.d ? a.b.c.d.e;
```

The reason for the `!` is to invert the test flag, to allow the success case to be the last expression in the `?:`. That allows us to chain them together like this.

*Do* check the operator precedence if you want to do this for real (I did some very basic tests and I think I got it right). And *do* expect people to point and laugh if they see it in your code.